# Speeding up GlusterFS in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, nfs, glusterfs, network-storage

I needed a good NFS storage cloud in AWS, and since EFS is just in preview mode, I did some research, and GFS looked like it would be the best bet.

Currently, I have two servers that are part of one cluster, each is using an EBS volume for the storage, and I was able to create them just fine, and I can read/write as well. But I think I'm having speed issues.

One of the volumes is shared between two web servers, and it holds the php files, which uses the Laravel framework, so theres a lot of files to install. Checking out the git repo and installing via `npm install` basically never ends, but if I go to a separate directory (not on NFS), and check out the same repo, it works fine, then I just rsync everything over (which again, takes much longer than I would expect, hours). The directory size of everything checked out is only **255M**, so I wouldn't think this would take that long.

I created a 1GB file using `dd` to see the speed:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=./test.txt bs=1024k count=1000 conv=sync
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 139.762 s, 7.5 MB/s
```

**7.5 MB/s** - Thats pretty slow I would think.

Would something like this be improved by adding more resources to the Glusterfs nodes? or adding more nodes to the cluster? Or is there throttling somewhere? I'm somewhat new to AWS, as well as GlusterFS, so any help would be appreciated.

#### UPDATE

Just an FYI, both instances are **t2.micro**, and in the **us-west-2a** AZ

Comment: For reference, with ext4 and a t2.micro I get 73MB/sec. Does your file system get faster with only one server attached? Could you use S3 instead of EBS? What instance size - could you check out to your instance disk if you have one and keep in sync?

Comment: What size instances are they? Smaller instance sizes may be limited to 100 Mbit.

Comment: @ceejayoz see my comment for t2.micro benchmark, which gets 580Mbps. That might be burst capacity rather than constant. I can scp between t2.micro instances at 50Mbps.

Comment: @ceejayoz I updated the post with the instance sizes.

Comment: @tim What do you mean by **could you check out to your instance disk if you have one and keep in sync**?

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried to find the **t2** instance sizes [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) and [here](http://www.ec2instances.info/), so im guessing its a pretty low speed.. maybe thats it..

Comment: @Justin Yeah, AWS doesn't put networks speeds in writing for most instance types. They do say `m4.large` has 450 Mbps to EBS, so I'd expect a `t2.micro` to have *significantly* less, particularly with noisy neighbors at times.

Comment: t2 instances have no instance stored - instance storage is a disk directly attached to the computer, as opposed to EBS which is network disk. If you had a C/M instance you could potentially use that.

Comment: @Tim the company im working for is pinching pennies, so Im trying to keep it as cheap as possible. I was thinking the [c4.large](http://www.ec2instances.info/?selected=c4.large), as its the cheapest EC2 with a listed network speed, lol. It only uses EBS as storage though, Do you think that would be a problem? Thats still almost $80/mo on demand, I doubt they would go for that

Comment: Spin up some spot instances and try them out. A spot instance costs about $0.04 an hour. You can reduce your prices with reserved instances, only after you're sure about your instance size and time you need it for of course. Given my t2.micro is going 10 times faster than yours you would probably be best reconsidering your file system choice and / or usage.